# Downloading data using HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, async-await

I'm working on a class to download some data from an external server and feed it into my data model.  I'm new to both `HttpClient` and `async` methods in C#, so I'm not sure of a few things.

1. Is my placement of `new SearchResultSet()` reasonable?  It's a little contrived, true, but I'm trying to get an example of how async code can streamline execution.
2. Is splitting the `GetStringAsync()` and `await myTask` statements going to cause any problems?

The `HttpClient` class is being passed in via the constructor to aid in unit testing.

```
class MySearch 
{
    private readonly HttpClient searchClient;
    private readonly Uri baseSearchUrl;

    public MySearch(HttpClient client, Uri baseUrl) {
        searchClient = client;
        baseSearchUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public async Task<SearchResultSet> SearchAsync(string term)
    {
        var query = "?gws_rd=ssl#q=" + term;
        var searchUrl = new Uri(baseSearchUrl, query);

        try {
            var myTask = searchClient.GetStringAsync(searchUrl);
            var result = new SearchResultSet()
            {
                SearchPageUrl = searchUrl
            };

            var searchData = await myTask;

            result.Fill(searchData); //parsing HTML is off-topic for this class!

            return result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }       
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You are making your class variables `readonly` which is good because they won't change.
- what I don't like is your mixing of the bracing style. Sometimes you use the [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style), sometimes the [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) and sometimes another style.

  Usually in C# one would expect to see Allman style only. If you want to use another style, that is pretty fine as long as you stick to it.
- the exception handling like you are doing it is superfluous and is destroying the stacktrace. Please read: [is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/730255/2655508)

  Because you are never handling the exceptions you could just remove the `try..catch` completely.